# How do you document the mandatory presence of a header?

Tags: node.js, express, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I know, there is jsdoc documentation, but I could not find my answer there, so I apologize if my question seems stupid.
I need the API documentation to indicate the need for the **x-auth-token** header with the value of the previously obtained token. How to do it?

Comment: You can use "require-header" dependency in your nodejs project to check for the mandatory headers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I chose a simpler and more understandable library for API documentation - apidocjs.
Another library that I also liked is OpenAPI